# Google Spreadsheet - remove cells depending on dropdown choice

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have a Spreadsheet like the image (choice is yes/no) https://i.ibb.co/6DS8NcF/cells.jpg

Is it possible to remove a row of cells when user clicks 'yes'? And that the removed row goes to another sheet?

I have some basic knowledge of GAS so if it is possible with GAS that's fine.

I already asked Google but they don't know if it is possible.

**Edit:**
This code does the first step, removing the cells with 'Yes' (thanks again for pushing me in the right direction).

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[5] == 'Yes') { // 0 for column A, 1 for B, etc
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};
```

I will post the next step as soon as I found out.

Comment: AppsScript has `onEdit()` triggers that run whenever a spreadsheet is changed. Check out [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite) to get started with this Simple Trigger. You can use the event argument that is passed in to check if the cell you want to observe has changed to 'Yes' and then do what you need.

Comment: @ChrisW Thank you, I will check it out

Comment: No problem. If you run into a problem in the future, please just ask!

Comment: @ChrisW nevermind, I forgot to change the searched column to 3. Stupid me.